# How do I get a YAML value inside another value with YAMLBeans

Tags: java, yaml

Sorry I didn't give such a good title. Here's my yml (databases.yml)

```
default: <br>
  #Default host - localhost <br>
  host: localhost <br>
  #Default username - root <br>
  username: root <br>
  #Default password - pass. Set to nopass for no password <br>
  password: pass <br>
  #Default database - BMod <br>
  database: bmod <br>
```

This is my java code:

```
    YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader(BMod.config+"/databases.yml")); <br>
    Object object = reader.read(); <br>
    System.out.println(object); <br>
    Map map = (Map)object; <br>
    System.out.println(map.get("default")); <br>
```

As you can see by System.out.println(map.get("default")); I can get values fine in the main file. But say I want to get "default.host". How do I do this with YAMLBeans?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
 System.out.println(map.get("default").get("host"));
```